# Location Search

Tags: jquery, google-maps, search

Hi I'm trying to work on some search functionality for a webpage I'm working on at the moment and i need a search box that will auto-complete but only return - towns/cities, Country, Airports and resorts. i though i could use Google maps and just remove the map as the search box on https://maps.google.co.uk/ works pretty much how i want it to but i cannot find any documentation of how to replicate that in my page everything iv found deals with the actual map (that i don't actually want), any input would be welcome. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend using Yahoo's YQL service to populate your autocomplete instead. It can return json so its perfect for jquery.

[Example in Yahoos YQL console to retreive results if someone starts typing PER](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22los%2a%22%20and%20country.code=%22US%22%20%20limit%202#h=select%20name%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22per%2a%22%20limit%2010)
So you would plug this url into your autocomplete function:

```
var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20name%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22" + THE_INPUT_TEXT + "*%22%20limit%2010&format=json";
```

Then capture all the results.place.name results as autocomplete options